# Powershell - Replace numbers in files

Tags: powershell

I need to write a script that goes into all the files in the folders&subfolders and replace the numbers in the range 888450-999450 to 222580-111620 at random.

for example:
My current folder is fold1
In fold1 there are two txt files and one folder named fold2.
In fold2 there is one txt file.

All the txt files contains strings like 888450@example.com and i want to replace it in the range specified at random.
There can be more folder and more text files.

I would happy to get help!

Thanks,
Danielo.

Comment: Should the new numbers be _unique_, ie. no two files get the same number?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried yourself already?

Answer (score 0):

here is my contribution:

I am not sure I understood correctly, I am not very fluent in English, but I am learning!

```
#Set your path here, on the first folder.
$path = "B:\Dev\fold1"

#Get the list of all *.txt, with recursivity
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.txt"

#Replace the elements
$initialvar= '789'
$newvar = $null

foreach($item in $list)
{
#you get a random value between 111111 and 2222222 
$newvar = Get-Random -Minimum 111111 -Maximum 2222222 

#here in each file, you replace the initial value(789) with the new value
(Get-Content $item) -replace $initialvar,$newvar | Set-Content $item
}
```

But you need to know the initial value you want to replace.

Comment: In the -replace you can use the regular expression '[89]\d{5}' rather than $initialvar. Here's a demo of the regex- https://regexr.com/5ah8b

Comment: Oh i see, with this regex you will replace every value begining with a 8 or 9 and folowed by 5 digits. You are right, it's better like this.